# how to make a responsive unwrap for a table column in bootstrap?

Tags: css, button, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

So this is a part of my code which creates a table using bootstrap. The last column stores three button `Show` , `Delete`, `Edit`. The column should expand enough to put all the three buttons on the same line. However in my chrome browser I get something like this.
[image: actual on screen]

The code below is saved in a file like StudentList.blade.php and called by a file Student.blade.php

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">CNE</th>
        <th scope="col">First Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Age</th>
        <th scope="col">Speciality</th>
        <th scope="col">Operations</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach($students as $student)
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>{{ $student->cne }}</td>
        <td>{{ $student->firstName }}</td>
        <td>{{ $student->LastName }}</td>
        <td>{{ $student->age }}</td>
        <td>{{ $student->Speciality }}</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Show</a>
          <a href="{{ url('/edit/'.$student->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Edit</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I am also including below the part of the Student.blade.php which invokes the above code just to let you guess if there is a conflict between the bootstrap stylings.

```
> <div class="container-fluid">
>       <div class="row">
>         <section class="col">
>             @include("studentList")
>         </section>
>         <section class="col"></section>
>       </div>  </div>
```

and also the codepen link where it seems perfectly fine
[table wrap as expected](https://codepen.io/code4mon/pen/MWKZqRY)

Comment: remove that `<th scope="row">1</th>`

Comment: Try `display: inline-table;` or `display: inline-flex;` for that `<td>`